# Google Earth Engine: Javascript to Python conversion: syntax error with `image1.and(image2)`

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I need to convert my Earth Engine javascript code into the Python API. 
Most of it works, but when using the following in Python (2.7):

```
mask = image1.and(image2)
```

I get:

```
File "<ipython-input-65-e84ccdaf9093>", line 41
    mask = image1.and(image2)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Though it works well with javascript. Any idea how to make this work? 
More generally, how to know which methods available in GEE docs are/are not implemented in the Python API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`and`, `or` and `not` are reserved words in Python, use `And`, `Or` and `Not`

```
mask = image1.And(image2)
```